# Help removing screws from this cabinet hinge

Tags: screws, hinges

Hi I need help removing screws from the side of the cabinet hinge found inside the cabinet carcass. Turning the screws does nothing to loosen them out, they just spin around. The screws seem to be inserted into some kind of green plastic spacer and then into a metal threaded dowel insert coated with plastic which anchors the screw. Even when I hold the metal/plastic threaded dowel piece at the end with locking pliers, the screw still won't budge out. I've already completely stripped one of the screw heads trying everything. We want to reuse this piece instead of buying a whole new hinge.

It would also be nice to know what the green spacer thing is actually called too since I can't seem to find the part on the internet. I'm afraid to cut it off since I don't know how to replace it.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The screws are part of the hinge base. They do not come apart from the part they are attached to.

That design was used in some "box" cabinets that you assemble yourself.

The holes in the sides of the cabinets were predrilled specifically to use those bases.  A full turn of a screwdriver and they are in. Then the hinges are attached to the door and the assembly is snaped on to the base.

The green part is proprietary to the hinge manufacturer. It was to prevent overtightening of the attachment screws.

You will be unable to reuse that hinge, unless you drill the proper size holes exactly where they need to be.  Not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

if they are really seized, as you suggest, then I would cut each screw coming down flush with the backside of the hinge.

A small hacksaw would be perfect for this or an oscillating saw may also work well.

When you need to refit, I would glue a suitable sized dowel into the hole - which will be sized for the green part and then redrill holes to  match new screws.